# Finding the length of the point from the ground where the tree was broken

Tags: trigonometry

A vertically straight tree, $15$ $m$ high, is broken by the wind in such a way that its top just touches the ground and makes an angle of $60^{\circ}$ with the ground. At what height from the ground did the tree break?

Attached below is the diagram that I have drawn. Kindly check that along with what I've tried already.

[image: Diagram]

What I've tried,

Let $CD=x$ $m$

$\therefore$ $AC=(15-x)$ $m$

In $\triangle ACB$, we have:-

$tan$ ${60}^{\circ}$=$\frac{AC}{AB}$

$\sqrt3$=$\frac{15-x}{AB}$

But, I cant carry on further.

Comment: Use $sin$ instead: $CD=CB=x$.

Comment: @AbhishekStudent. Sketched angle should also reasonably look like it is 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the length of the stick which is broken off. The length of the stick which is not broken off will therefore be $15-n$. Note that the stick which is broken off is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, while the stick which is not broken off is one of the legs. Also, notice that the sine function is the **opposite over the hypotenuse**. So if $n$ is the hypotenuse and $15-n$ is the side opposite the angle, we get that

$$\frac{15-n}{n} = \sin{60^o}$$

which, using the unit circle evaluates to $\sqrt{3/4}$. Now we get the equation

$$\frac{15-n}{n} = \sqrt{3/4}$$

which simplifies to

$$15-n = n\sqrt{3/4}$$
$$15 = n + n\sqrt{3/4}$$
$$15 = n(1 + \sqrt{3/4})$$
$$n=15(1+\sqrt{3/4})$$

Therefore, the hypotenuse is $15(1+\sqrt{3/4})$. Solve from here.

Comment: Yeah! I've got the answer thanks to you! Your answer was quite elaborative. Thanks once again sir!

Comment: So $n\approx 28$ ...

Comment: @Abhishekstudent It would help if you could press the check mark next to my answer. That way, we both get reputations, and those viewing this question know my answer both helped and satisfied the needs of the questioner :)

Answer (score 0):

Without trigonometry: you know that $2AB=BC$, hence $x^2=(15-x)^2+(x/2)^2$